# Call button click function from grandchild

Tags: c++, events, popup, wxwidgets

I'm creating my first C++ wxWidgets application. I'm trying to create some kind of split button where the options are displayed in a grid. I have a custom button class which, when right-clicked on, opens a custom wxPopupTransientWindow that contains other buttons.
When I click on the buttons in the popup, I want to simulate a left click on the main button. I'm trying to achieve this through events, but I'm kinda confused.

```
void expandButton::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    if (pressed) {
        pressed = false;
        paintNow();

        wxWindow* mBtn = this->GetGrandParent();
        mBtn->SetLabel(this->GetLabel());
        mBtn->Refresh();

        wxCommandEvent event(wxEVT_BUTTON);
        event.SetId(GetId());
        event.SetEventObject(mBtn);
        mBtn-> //make it process the event somehow?

        wxPopupTransientWindow* popup = wxDynamicCast(this->GetParent(), wxPopupTransientWindow);
        popup->Dismiss();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `mBtn->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent()`.

Comment: if `mBtn` already has an event handler for processing the event, then use wxQeueEvent and set the destination to `m_Btn`. https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#gae921d7bd0e52fedbf3f253d2c408bce1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `mBtn->ProcessWindowEvent()` which is a shorter synonym for `mBtn->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent()` already mentioned in the comments.

Note that, generally speaking, you're not supposed to create `wxEVT_BUTTON` events from your own code. In this particular case and with current (and all past) version(s) of wxWidgets it will work, but a cleaner, and guaranteed to also work with the future versions, solution would be define your own custom event and generate it instead.